# chunk NP and VP using nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to use nltk to find noun phrase (NP) and verb phrase (VP) in some LaTeX files.
my LaTeX files contains lots of maths. As I am new to nltk I start trying to get what I need from the terminal. so for example I tried this sentence:

Let the sizes be denoted by `$s(n)$` and `$t(n)$` respectively.

the code I tried:

```
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag

>>> text = "Let the sizes be denoted by $s(n)$ and $t(n)$ respectively."

>>> sents = sent_tokenize(text)

>>> tokens = word_tokenize(text)

>>> tagged_tokens = pos_tag(tokens)
```

and all these worked fine. but when I tried these:

```
>>> from nltk.chunk import *

>>> from nltk.chunk.util import *

>>> from nltk.chunk.regexp import *

>>> from nltk import Tree

>>> gold_chunked_text = tagstr2tree(tagged_tokens)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/chunk/util.py", line 331, in tagstr2tree
    for match in WORD_OR_BRACKET.finditer(s):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tagstr2tree()` function expects a string input but you've given it a list of tuples output by `pos_tag()`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = "Let the sizes be denoted by $s(n)$ and $t(n)$ respectively."
>>> tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
>>> tagged_text
[('Let', 'NNP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('sizes', 'NNS'), ('be', 'VB'), ('denoted', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('$', '$'), ('s', 'NNS'), ('(', 'CD'), ('n', 'NN'), (')', ':'), ('$', '$'), ('and', 'CC'), ('$', '$'), ('t', 'NN'), ('(', ':'), ('n', 'NN'), (')', ':'), ('$', '$'), ('respectively', 'RB'), ('.', '.')]
```

Now you see that `pos_tag` might not be giving you what you need so maybe this is a better way to tokenize:

```
>>> tagged_text = pos_tag(text.split())
>>> tagged_text
[('Let', 'NNP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('sizes', 'NNS'), ('be', 'VB'), ('denoted', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('$s(n)$', 'NNP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('$t(n)$', 'NNP'), ('respectively.', 'NNP')]
```

Going back to the tagstr2tree, the expected input looks like this:

```
'Let/NNP the/DT sizes/NNS be/VB denoted/VBN by/IN $s(n)$/NNP and/CC $t(n)$/NNP respectively./NNP'
```

To achieve that do:

```
>>> " ".join(["{}/{}".format(word,pos) for word, pos in tagged_text])
```

Here's the full script:

```
>>> from nltk.chunk.util import tagstr2tree
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> text = "Let the sizes be denoted by $s(n)$ and $t(n)$ respectively."
>>> tagged_text = pos_tag(text.split())
>>> tagged_text_string = " ".join(["{}/{}".format(word,pos) for word, pos in tagged_text])
>>> tagstr2tree(tagged_text_string)
Tree('S', [('Let', 'NNP'), ('the', 'DT'), ('sizes', 'NNS'), ('be', 'VB'), ('denoted', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('$s(n)$', 'NNP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('$t(n)$', 'NNP'), ('respectively.', 'NNP')])
```